# set duration when dialog open or leave angular 13

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material, dialog

I'm using NgDialogAnimationService on angular 13 and it all works fine, but one thing is missing
I need to set the duration property for when the dialog opens and leaves but I can't, some can help!

```
import { NgDialogAnimationService } from 'ng-dialog-animation';

    private dialogs:NgDialogAnimationService,


  onView(row: any) {
    this.dialogs.open(LogViewComponent, {
      width: "250px",
      animation: { to: "aside" },
      data: {
        dialogData: row,
      }

    }).afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      // this.loadData();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use keyframe option:

```js
animation: {
        to: "aside",
        incomingOptions: {
          keyframeAnimationOptions: { duration: 1000, easing: "steps(7, end)" }
        }
      },
```

Check this out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-animation?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts,app%2Fdialog-overview-example.html

Comment: Zsolt Balint Special Thanks for you

Comment: do you know how to use fadeIn and fadeOut !

Comment: Show me a sample what do you want to do and will tray to help you.

Comment: 'animation' does not exist in type 'MatDialogConfig' while adding animation property